# What is Kaohsiung and Taipei like 1 week after Chinese New Year

Tags: event-based-effects, taiwan, vacations, taipei

May I know what is the condition after 1 week of Chinese new year in Kaohsiung and Taipei? Will it be crowded with a lot of people?

I am planning to go to Kaohsiung and Taipei next year February 6 to 15 and I was wondering if there will be people to help us with like taxi, mrt train and other things like restaurant and night market, will they still be open? 
I would like to know all these things before I can plan properly for my parent as they didn't go to Taiwan before.

Comment: Taipei is a city of nearly three million people. Any city of that size will surely be busy the whole time, and taxis, public transit and restaurants will be available throughout the year. Could you clarify what exactly you're asking about? What do you mean by "people to help us"?

Comment: The Chinese New Year Holiday of 2017 ends on February 1 in Taiwan. So by February 6 everything should be normal and business as usual. While some restaurants and night markets may not be open for business DURING the holiday, by February 6 they will have been opened. Taxis and MRT services are available all year round.